# Moving objects with mass

Tags: lua, collision, velocity, bounce

How does a moving object slow down when it hits a stationary object?

They transfer velocity, but how do they slow down? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, rather than as an addendum to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually they transfer energy not Velocity.
A good way to think about that when the first object hits the second object , it does force on the second one in direction of its movement which cause the second object to accelerate.but acc. to the third law of Newton the second object does also  a force on the first one  but in the opposite direction which cause  acceleration but in the opposite direction of movement of the first object , therefore the first object or even change its direction.
hope it helps

Comment: The thought of transferring energy helps. The bounce of velocity from the first object to its self solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As explained above, the object moving applies a force in the direction of its moving to the other object. But the other object also applies a force with the same intensity and contrary direction on the object moving. What the two objects gain is acceleration, not velocity. According to the second Newton law, the acceleration each object gains (in m/s/s) is equal to the force applied (in Newtons) divided by its mass (in kgs).

Comment: This is helpful for ball bounce. `A` hits `B`, in direction between, `A` forces `B`, `A` `-`forces `A`. `B` does the same if moving. The percentage of force loss is determined by the masses. Right?

Comment: How is the loss of energy determined when balls bounce? Large hits small will barely show loss of force, but small hits large head on deflects the same amount of force.

Comment: I said it. Acceleration = force / mass. Say the force is 15 N. The Bigger object  (mass 5 for example) will gain an acceleration of 15 / 5 = 3 meters per square second. The smaller object (mass 3) will gain more acceleration: 15 / 3 = 5 m / s / s.

Comment: So when two balls hit, do each balls lose energy and give to the other or is it added and deflected? Example: a bowling ball will hit a ping-pong ball with pretty much no slowness, else hitting another bowling ball bounce back.